# AngularJS formatting based on expression result

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand how to accomplish conditional formatting with AngularJS.

My scenerio, I have a table with a bunch of values like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat='r in row'>
  <td>{{r.valueA | number:0}}</td>
  <td>{{r.valueB | number:0}}</td>
  <td>{{r.valueA - r.valueB | number:0}}</td>
  <td>{{total.valueA - r.valueA | number:0}}</td>
  <td>{{total.valueA - (r.valueA - r.valueB | number:0)}}</td>
</tr>
```

*What I want to happen is for these cells to change the text red when the number is negative.*

Below is what I have tried:

**A)** Using the `ng-class` directive route:

```
<tr ng-repeat='r in row'>
  <td ng-class="{'text-red':r.valueA < 0}">{{r.valueA | number:0}}</td>
  <td ng-class="{'text-red':r.valueB < 0}">{{r.valueB | number:0}}</td>
  <td ng-class="{'text-red':(r.valueA - r.valueB) < 0}">{{r.valueA - r.valueB | number:0}}</td>
  <td ng-class="{'text-red':(total.valueA - r.valueA) < 0}">{{total.valueA - r.valueA | number:0}}</td>
  <td ng-class="{'text-red':(total.valueA - (r.valueA - r.valueB)) < 0}">{{total.valueA - (r.valueA - r.valueB) | number:0}}</td>
</tr>
```

...and it works, but there is a lot of needless typing. Surely there is a better way.

**B)** A custom filter but cannot get it to work:

```
myApp.filter('numberVariance',
    ['$filter',
    function (filter) {
        var numberFilter = filter('number');
        return function (amount, fractionDigits) {
            if (value === "0") {
                return "-";
            }
            var value = numberFilter(amount, fractionDigits);
            if (amount < 0)
                return "<span class='text-red'>" + value + "</span>";
            return value;
        };
    }]);
```

...this escapes the returned HTML string. I would rather find a solution that does not use `ng-html-bind` or "unsafe" strings.

**C)** A custom directive. This feels like it is the best fit, but I cannot get this to work either:

```
myApp.directive('varianceValue', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            $(el).toggleClass("text-red", ($(el).text().indexOf('-') > -1));
        },
    }
});
```

...this works fine on first load, but does not toggle the class as the value updates.

Comment: Just a comment on C) custom directive.  You aren't watching for anything to change so it won't toggle the class.  Either use scope.$on  or attr.$observe to watch for a change and run your jQuery toggle again.

Comment: @fiskers7 I got it working with scope.$watch. Should I have used one of the others you mention instead?

Comment: Either one works, it really comes down to how your directive is setup and used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $timeout gives Angular time to evaluate the expression and your directive should  work just fine.

Working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/caPNCf2KPSTYhbYFVNEh?p=preview)

```
app.directive('varianceValue', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
          $timeout(function(){
            $(el).toggleClass("text-red", ($(el).text().indexOf('-') > -1));
          },0);
        },
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in row">
      <td variance-value>{{r.valueA | number:0}}</td>
      <td variance-value>{{r.valueB | number:0}}</td>
      <td variance-value>{{r.valueA - r.valueB | number:0}}</td>
      <td variance-value>{{total.valueA - r.valueA | number:0}}</td>
      <td variance-value>{{total.valueA - (r.valueA - r.valueB | number:0)}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This clearly works in your example, but it does not work for me. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I got this to work by using `scope.$watch('row'` instead of the `$timeout`. Here is a fork of your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwtxVEY1qRiqOLf0u9QR?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could use the angular `ng-class` directive, to add the appropriarate class when the computed value is negative.

It is the cleanest approach (using the angular philosophy) because:

- it uses a CSS class that is binded to a computed variable
- every part of this solution has a distinct role ( css for the
  visuals, a true/false value to control the class )
- it is flexible, easy to be modified and can be easily scaled up ( add
  more classes, different logic in getting the colors according to the
  value etc)
- The computations are performed in the controller
- As for the extra typing: It can be further reduced by adding an additional (nested) ng-repeat to generate the `<td>`'s for each row.

A working example:

HTML:

```
<style>
    .red {
        color: red
    }
</style>

<span ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat='r in row'>
            <td ng-class="{ red: isRed(getColumnVal(r, 1)) }">
                {{getColumnVal(r, 1)}}
            </td>
            <td ng-class="{ red: isRed(getColumnVal(r, 2)) }">
                {{getColumnVal(r, 2)}}
            </td>
            <td ng-class="{ red: isRed(getColumnVal(r, 3)) }">
                {{getColumnVal(r, 3)}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    // the array of objects*
    $scope.row = [
        {
            valueA: 1,
            valueB: 2
        },
        {
            valueA: 3,
            valueB: 4
        }
    ];

    // returns the value for the given object* and the given table column
    $scope.getColumnVal = function (o, col) {
        var columnVal = 0;

        switch (col) {
            case 1:
                columnVal = o.valueA
                break;
            case 2:
                columnVal = o.valueB;
                break;
            case 3:
                columnVal = o.valueA - o.valueB;
                break;
            default: 
                columnVal = 0;
        }

        return columnVal;
    };

    // returns true if the given val is smaller than zero, else returns false
    $scope.isRed = function (val) {
        var isRed = false;
        if (val < 0) {
            isRed = true;
        }
        return isRed;
    };

}]);
```

To further reduce the typping:

avoid writting each `<td>` by adding an additional `ng-repeat`

HTML:

```
<style>
    .red {
        color: red
    }
</style>
<span ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat='r in row'>
            <td ng-repeat='c in columns' ng-class="{ red: isRed(getColumnVal(r, c)) }">
                {{getColumnVal(r, c)}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>
```

and add to the controller the following statement that defines the columns, according to your needs:

```
$scope.columns = [1, 2, 3]; // This is for 3 columns, extend to your needs
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I will have to think on it, and there is a lot here I can take away. I am new to angular and still learning the philosophy; though this does seem to add controller-view coupling just for the view to do a basic conditional formatting. I appreciate your suggestion on repeating the table cells as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ng-class, but pull the logic out into descriptively named functions in the controller/service depending on how your app is set up.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I ended up going with. Thank you all for your contributions.

```
myApp.directive('varianceValue', [ function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attr) {
            scope.$watch(
                function () { return el.text() },
                function () { $(el).toggleClass("text-red", ($(el).text().indexOf('-') > -1)); }
            );
        },
    }
}]);
```

I messed around with various $watch values and most of them brought the application to a crawl, but the version above is holding strong.